# Cronjob call php script failed

Tags: php, include, cron, require

I want to run a php script every 2 hours. The php script have includes und requires in his code

my system is a ubuntu server

so to set up the cron i used

```
env EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

there i wrote the cronjob like.. (every 5 minutes for testing)

```
*/5 * * * * wget http://www.domain.de/cron.php?id=ID&pw=PW
```

and tried also

```
*/5 * * * * wget http://www.domain.de/cron.php?id=ID&pw=PW > /dev/null 2>&1
```

the above i used in plesk but here i got only a shell connect by putty

What happens is that a file is written in main directory of the webspace with text inside Zutritt verweigert (access denied)

i have no htaccess or something like that in the directory

Comment: i allready checked id and pw - the values are correct

Comment: what happens if you put `http://www.domain.de/cron.php?id=ID&pw=PW` in your web browser?

Comment: if i put this in the webbrowser it works correctly ..

Answer (score 0):

You should add quotes around the URL:

```
*/5 * * * * wget "http://www.domain.de/cron.php?id=ID&pw=PW"
```

They are needed so the `&` symbol doesn't get mucked.

Comment: ok now i dont get an file written in main directory with access denied but the script still doesnt work. The Script have includes and fopen maybe that is the reason for why it didnt work ?

Comment: That would be a separate question from this; open another question about the functionality of your script.